# onpointerdown e.stopPropagation not working in IE/Edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, touch-event, pointer-events

I have tried disable link redirect on hybrid device (touchscreen laptop) by using event.stopPropagation() method and also event.preventDefault() method in event handler 'onpointerdown'. But it seems that is not working at all. Logs says that event was  triggered but method does not stop redirect propagation. I am using onpointer down as alternative way for "touchstart" handling in IE/Edge which has not "touch" event presented as I have read.

There is my code

```
$('.main-menu u li a').on('pointerdown', function (e) {
    console.log('pointer down on menu');
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).find('.megamenu').addClass('open');
});
```

Comment: `preventDefualt` you have a misspelling. It's likely that this is causing a runtime error and thus the rest of the code won't be executed.

Comment: oh well, this misspelling I made when type so it's not presented in code in real, but thanks for warning